# Make configuration file point to an existing file

Tags: shell, routes, tcl, configuration-files, eda

qrouter [-c < config_name>] [options] < basename>

```
 where <basename> is without an extension.
 File <basename>.def is assumed to exist
 and to define cell placement and netlist
 information.  File <config_name> is
 assumed to exist and contains basic
 routing parameters, or points to a LEF
 file containing detailed routing parameters.
 If this option is not specified, then the
 default configuration file name of "route.cfg"
 is used.
```

How to write a .cfg file that points to an existing file?

Comment: When you are using a Linux environment try to create a soft link (named <config_name>.cfg) that points to the existing config file.

Answer (score 0):

The commend is used to run an open source VLSI routing tool called Qrouter, an example .cfg file can be like below:

lef    /usr/lib/ibm01.lef